# TextFormField initialValue gets the value of the next field when I remove the First TextFormField in a List

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

First of all, I'm sorry for the title, it is a little bit complicated to understand.

1 - I create the TEXTFORMFIELDs of my form dynamicaly.
2 - When I try to remove TEXTFORMFIELD (except the last), it get deleted and the DATA in PROVIDER change, but the next TEXTFORMFIELD takes the INITIALVALUE of the deleted TEXTFORMFIELD.

WIDGET CODE :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/players.dart';

class PlayersNameForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final players = Provider.of<Players>(context);
    final playersData = players.players;
    final playersCount = players.count();

    return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(playersCount, (index) =>
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: playersData[index].name,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Joueur ' + (index + 1).toString(),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete_outline,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    players.removePlayerByIndex(index);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PROVIDER CODE :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './player.dart';

class Players with ChangeNotifier{
  List<Player> _players = [
    Player(
      name: 'Player A'
    ),
    Player(
      name: 'Player B'
    ),
    Player(
      name: 'Player C'
    ),
    Player(
      name: 'Player D'
    ),
  ];

  List<Player> get players {
    return [..._players];
  }

  int count(){
    return _players.length;
  }

  void addPlayer(){
    int count = this.count();

    if(count < 4){
      _players.add(Player(name: ''));
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void removePlayer(){
    int count = this.count();

    if(count > 2) {
      _players.removeLast();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void removePlayerByIndex(index){
    _players.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Comment: Try StateFull widget and declare your `final players = Provider.of<Players>(context);` outside of the build method.

Comment: You can't declare it before the build method, because they are no context. I tried it in a StatefullWidget, and the same behavior.

Comment: you can do it inside initState of statefull widget